# Dependent DropDown Does not working in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i'm trying to load particular dataset for dropdown.using data models.

first when i selected the floor particular hall names should be load into the system.i have a problem when i selected any floor all the hall name will loaded into the dropdown.

**This is my floor Model**

```
class FloorModel {
  final int id;
  final String floorname;
  final String floorimg;
  final String floorshortname;

  FloorModel(this.id, this.floorname, this.floorimg, this.floorshortname);
}
```

**This is my Hall Model**

```
class HallModel {
  final int id;
  final String hallname;
  final String hallpoint;
  final String hallshortname;

  HallModel(this.id, this.hallname, this.hallpoint, this.hallshortname);
}
```

**this is my class file .i need to filter out the hall list according to selected floor**

```
class FOCMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const FOCMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<FOCMap> createState() => _FOCMapState();
}
List<FloorModel> floorlist = [
  FloorModel(1, 'Ground Floor', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  FloorModel(2, '1st floor', 'img/first.jpeg', 'first'),
  FloorModel(3, '2nd Floor', 'img/second.jpeg', 'second'),
  FloorModel(4, 'B1 Floor', 'img/b1.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  FloorModel(5, 'B2 Floor', 'img/b2.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  FloorModel(6, 'B3 Floor', 'img/b3.jpeg', 'BThree'),
];

List<HallModel> halllist = [
  HallModel(1, '001', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(2, '002', 'img/first.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(3, '003', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(4, '004', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(5, '005', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(6, '006', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(7, '007-Computer Lab', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(8, '008-Computer Lab', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(9, '009', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(10, 'Program Office', 'img/second.jpeg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(11, '101', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(12, '102', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(13, '103', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(14, '104', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(15, '105', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(16, '106', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(17, '107', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(18, '108', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(19, '109', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(20, '110', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(21, '111', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(22, '112', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(23, '113', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(24, '114', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(25, '201', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(26, '202', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(27, '203', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(28, '204-Lab', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(29, '205-Lab', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(30, 'Acadamic Staff', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
];

FloorModel _selectedfloorModel = floorlist.first;
HallModel _selectedhallModel = halllist.first;

String select_img = '';


class _FOCMapState extends State<FOCMap> {

  check(){
    halllist.forEach ((e){

      if(e.hallshortname == _selectedfloorModel.floorshortname){
        print(e.hallpoint); // for halllist image
        setState((){
          select_img = e.hallpoint;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Faculty of Computing"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(_selectedfloorModel.floorimg),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              DropdownButton<FloorModel>(
                  value: _selectedfloorModel,
                  items: floorlist.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<FloorModel>(
                      child: Text(item.floorname),
                      value: item,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    setState((){
                      _selectedfloorModel = value!;
                    });

                    check();
                  }
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              DropdownButton<HallModel>(
                  value: _selectedhallModel,
                  items: halllist.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<HallModel>(
                      child: Text(item.hallname),
                      value: item,
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value){
                    setState((){
                      _selectedhallModel = value!;
                    });
                  }
              ),
              Text(select_img)
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

please anyone have idea please give some support for me .thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a third list, which is the **filtered Hall List**, in which you store the Halls based on the selection of the floor.

```
List<HallModel> filteredHallList = []
```

After this, when your **floor selection changes**, you call a method (or function) to change the values of the `filteredhallList`.

In your view, instead of loading the hall list you have right now, always use the **filteredHallList**, for the dropdown. This will ensure that the hall list is only used to modify the filter, without losing its values.